# Android application with different build type having same package name

Tags: android, firebase

If I have like the following

```
Debug: com.test.project
Staging: com.test.project
Release: com.test.project
```

Of-course the release will be uploaded to the Play Store, Huawei Store, and Samsung Store -if possible-
1) Will this cause any type of problems?
2) If I created a firebase project to each build type,will I be getting any type of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. It's not possible to have two apps with the same ID and SHA-1 hash registered with Firebase.  If you want to have two apps with the same ID, then you will need to sign them with different keys.